# Rails link_to "New Post", '#' with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey i am trying to make it so that when a button is pressed a modal pops up but the modal needs some data from the parameters of the url. E.g. im on:

```
localhost:3000/posts
```

and i click the button, I need the url to change to this:

```
localhost:3000/posts?comments_id=14
```

i have this so far:

```
= link_to "Add Post", '#'(comments_id: @comments.id)
```

Which obviously doesn't work but you can probably see what I am trying to do

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
= link_to "Add Post", posts_path(comments_id: @comments.id)
```

**or**

```
= link_to "Add Post", "/posts?comments_id=#{@comments.id}"
```